# UI component with ion-tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m trying to create header/Navbar component for my tabs but facing an issue in the component with ion-tabs.

it raises an Error: `1. If ‘custom-header’ is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`

I have tried to load my component in a normal page in the same project it works fine in it.
but in tabs, it raises an ERROR.

Here is my code.

**navbar.html**

```
<ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title></ion-title>

        <ion-chip>
            <button ion-button clear color="light">
              <ion-icon class="fa fa-microphone"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-chip>
      </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

my selector in `navbar.ts`

**my component.module.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'navbar',
   templateUrl: 'navbar.html'
 })
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [NavbarComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [NavbarComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**My Tabs Main/Parent Page**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashboardPage } from './dashboard';
import { ComponentsModule }from '../../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardPage,
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(DashboardPage),
    ComponentsModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardPageModule {}
```

I have added this component in `app.module.ts`
any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the `Components.module.ts` file under the `declarations` and `exports` section.After that, you need to `imports` `ComponentsModule` on your tab page's `module`. If you have any question please let me know.

Comment: Dear I followed your steps. but still facing the same.
When I add `component.module.ts` in child/content Tab and parent/main tab it shows this error.
`Error: Type NavbarComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules.`
but when I add this only in Main/parent tab it shows `navbar is not a known element: 1. If navbar is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`

Comment: I have also added my **component.module.ts** code in question.

Comment: it solved my error. I followed your steps and  just added my component in tab's firstPage module's declaration.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: hmm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import NavController on navbar.ts

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
...
constructor (public navCtrl: NavController) {
   ...
}
```